# Customize bootstrap button font

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sass

I'm using sass-version of Bootstrap and want to customize the buttons' font, so that it differs from the system font.

I don't see any sass/less variables that would modify the font-family of my buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#buttons

So, how do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `font-family` of button elements is inherited from the `@font-family-sans-serif` variable. The variable as standard is `"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`. You can find the variable [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#typography).

You can override it the `btn` class in your ccs with something like:

```
.btn {
    font-family: SomeFont;
}
```

I would recommend doing this in your own stylesheet rather than changing the bootstrap one though.

Comment: I've used additional _bootswatch.scss file, where overridden .btn font style as you recommend. Seems, like bootstrap just doesn't present a variable for overriding font-family in elements.

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4, the SASS variables `$input-btn-font-family` and `$btn-font-family` are available.

**Bootstrap 4.5 :**

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss

$input-btn-font-family:       null !default;
$btn-font-family:             $input-btn-font-family !default;


./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss


.btn {

>  font-family: $btn-font-family;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another class to override the btn class

```
.yourownclass{
     font-family: "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 15px ! important; //to make fontsize bigger 
  }
```

your HTML should be look like

```
    <input  type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary yourownclass"/>
```